# Angular2 Web Deployment in VS2015(Framework 4.6)

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, bundling-and-minification, angular2-aot

I am having problem while deploying my **Angular2 Vs2015** application. I have created my application and deployed in Server.
When i request for LogIn Page for the 1st time. its loading all **node_modules** and other files and taking nearly 2 mins to load application for the 1st time.

I would like to go with **AoT(Angular2)**. But i did not find any articles or support for **Bundling**,**Minification**,**Uglify** etc and my application should load fast.

## Vs2015, #Angular2.....

**Reference :** https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html
and https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html

Comment: angular-cli(built-in-webpack) + rollup + aot, these combination would do the trick.. refer this documentation link https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html

Comment: I have done this, but i am having problem while deployment. When i deploy it , it says 'Require' is undefined.

Comment: your question is totally contradicting with what you're saying now.. please update your question with correct information.

Comment: did you deploy angular2 Aot Compiled in IIS, if so please help me in deployment. If you have any other solution or suggestions always appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't deployed AOT version of application on IIS, I tried several things on local, and they got work as expected :) Can't suggest anything on deployment part :(